# Can LEDs be powered from a power supply instead of batteries without getting too much current?

Tags: led, current

I'm very used to powering individual LEDs with a battery and I'm not usually concerned about putting too much current into them, however, I worry that using power from an outlet that can do 1 A DC will burn through my 20 mA max. LEDs.

Is this actually a problem? Or can something be added in-between to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very small battery like a coin cell has a high internal resistance that can limit the current to a level that is safe for an LED, so sometimes you can get away with not adding a resistor.

All other voltage sources require a resistor in series with the LED to set and limit the current through the LED.

You need to find out the forward voltage V<sub>f</sub> of your LED from its datasheet, and the voltage of your power source. The power source voltage minus V<sub>f</sub> is the voltage that needs to drop across the resistor.

Take the voltage that drops across the resistor you just calculated and divide it by 20 mA (or any other current you want to use) to get the resistor's value.

Example:
5 V power supply, LED forward voltage drop V<sub>f</sub> = 2 V, LED current is 10 mA.

The resistor needs to drop 5 V - 2 V = 3 V; 3 V divided by 10 mA = 3 V / 0.01 A = 300 Ω.

Comment: Oh okay awesome! So the LED won't pull more current than 20mA? Is the actual reason LED's burn out usually to high of a voltage rather than current?

Comment: @KidWithComputer High voltage causes there to be high current. High current causes high heat.

Comment: @KidWithComputer LEDs are very non-linear, meaning they let almost no current up until a certain voltage (depending on the type of LED can be from 1.5V to 3.5V) when its current starts rising sharply, and raising the voltage by just 10% can easily raise an LED's current by 100%, which means that without any sort of a current limiting device (like a resistor, a constant current source or current regulator) LEDs are doomed to destruction.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's very common to use LEDs in circuits that are powered by power supplies  rather than by batteries.

You can, for example, design a constant current power supply (rather than a constant voltage one). This is typically done with several LEDs arranged in series, for example in lighting applications.

Or you can simply use some other means to limit the current to the LED when it is powered by a constant-voltage source. A series resistor is a very common way of doing this.